# Gzip Compression inbuilt Functionality in Wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress, wordpress-theming

i was changing the site **url** and **home**  in database , i found there is one row data like

```
    optionid   optionname   optionvalue   autoload

    31         gzipcompression  0          yes

    32         hack_file        0          yes
```

here in table field  i found above data in my wordpress databse.

what is hack_file??    **is gzip compression already there in  wordpress?**

how to chanage the option value?> how to mange it?  any idea..

[image]

Comment: With respect, Google turns up an entry in the WordPress Codex describing these options.

Comment: seems like you have more knowledge about it. i think you should share it ..http://yourdomain.com/wp-admin/options.php   i found this but still  don't know why it is not ther ein setting section? is it useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**gzip compression**

You will have to turn the gzip compression on in your settings:

1. Log in to your WordPress admin.
2. Navigate to: wp-admin/options.php
3. Scroll down to gzipcompression and change the value in the field
   from 0 to 1. This sets GZip compression to “true” in WordPress.

See: http://workfunc.com/gzip-compression-make-wordpress-fly/

**hack_file**

1. Log in to your WordPress admin.
2. Navigate to: wp-admin/options.php
3. Scroll down to hack_file and change the value in the field
   from 0 to 1.

Once this is enabled it checks for a file in your blog root folder called "my-hacks.php". If this file exists, then whatever code is in it is executed. If the file doesn't exist then nothing happens.